# how can I do multi-language using ajax in asp.net core mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, visual-studio, asp.net-core, multilingual

I am new in using Asp.net core mvc. My goal is to change the language using ajax I did it but I did not use ajax. Any idea of how can I do it?

Here is the link of changing the language on my (Layout) view, I called the action.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("LanguageChange", "Home", new {returnUrl})"> @Resource.LanguageText </a>
```

And on the home controller the action (Language change):

```
        public IActionResult LanguageChange(string returnUrl)
    {
        var language = "en-US";

        if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name.Equals("en-US"))
            language = "ar-SA";

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(language);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(language);

        Response.Cookies.Append(CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
            CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(language)));

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
```

Any idea how can I do it using Ajax? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Normally, a multilingual website would refresh and display localized content after website users selected their preferred the language/culture.

And in [this official doc with example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1#set-the-culture-programmatically), you would find that `_SelectLanguagePartial.cshtml` provides a dropdown list with supported cultures to enable the user to set the culture, then it would reach in `SetLanguage` method that sets the culture cookie and redirects user to a specific url to show localized content.

> Any idea how can I do it using Ajax?

If you make Ajax request to your `LanguageChange` method, the culture cookie would be set, but browser would not automatically redirect user to specific url and display localized content unless you manually do redirection or refresh on client side. So as demonstrated in official example, you can implement similar strategy to enable user to select the language/culture via dropdown list etc rather than making Ajax request to set/change the culture cookie.

[image]